# FLASK REST API returns 400 on POST

Tags: python, rest, flask, postman

I'm building a REST API for a simple Todo application using flask and SQLAlchemy as my ORM. I am testing my API using Postman. I'm on a windows 10 64-bit machine.

A GET request works and returns the data that I've entered into my database using python.

[image: Get Request]

I'd like to try to add a task now. But when I POST my request, I receive an error.

[image: POST request]

My route in flask looks like this.

```
#add task
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        raise InvalidUsage('Not a valid task!', status_code=400)
    task = {
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'description': request.json['description'],
        'done': False
    }
    Todo.add_todo(task)
    return jsonify({'task': task}), 201
```

And the method it's calling on the Todo object looks like this.

```
def add_todo(_title, _description):
    new_todo = Todo(title=_title, description=_description , completed = 0)
    db.session.add(new_todo)
    db.session.commit()
```

**What I've tried**

I thought that maybe the `'` in my Postman Params was causing an issue so I removed them. But I still get the same error.

Then I thought that maybe the way that Postman was sending the POST was incorrect so I checked to make sure that the Content-Type headers was correct. It is set to `application/json`

Finally, to confirm that the issue was that flask didn't like the request, I removed the check in the add task route to make sure the request had a title. So it looks like this.

```
if not request.json:
```

And I get the same error. So I think that the problem must be with how I'm actually sending the POST rather than some kind of formatting issue.

My entire code looks like this.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import json
from flask import jsonify
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(300), unique=False, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(), unique=False, nullable=False)
    completed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)

    def json(self):
        return {'id': self.id,'title': self.title, 'description': self.description, 'completed': self.completed}

    def add_todo(_title, _description):
        new_todo = Todo(title=_title, description=_description , completed = 0)
        db.session.add(new_todo)
        db.session.commit()

    def get_all_tasks():
        return [Todo.json(todo) for todo in Todo.query.all()]

    def get_task(_id):
        task = Todo.query.filter_by(id=_id).first()
        if task is not None:
            return Todo.json(task)
        else:
            raise InvalidUsage('No task found', status_code=400)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Todo('{self.title}')"




class InvalidUsage(Exception):
    status_code = 400

    def __init__(self, message, status_code=None, payload=None):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
        self.payload = payload

    def to_dict(self):
        rv = dict(self.payload or ())
        rv['message'] = self.message
        return rv

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello to the World of Flask!'

#get all tasks
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return_value = Todo.get_all_tasks()
    return jsonify({'tasks': return_value})

#get specific task
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    task = Todo.get_task(task_id)
    #if len(task) == 0:
        #raise InvalidUsage('No such task', status_code=404)
    return jsonify({'task': task})

#add task
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        raise InvalidUsage('Not a valid task!', status_code=400)
    task = {
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'description': request.json['description'],
        'done': False
    }
    Todo.add_todo(task)
    return jsonify({'task': task}), 201

#update task
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['PUT'])
def update_task(task_id):
    task = [task for task in tasks if task['id'] == task_id]
    if len(task) == 0:
        raise InvalidUsage('No provided updated', status_code=400)
    if not request.json:
        raise InvalidUsage('request not valid json', status_code=400)
    if 'title' in request.json and type(request.json['title']) != unicode:
        raise InvalidUsage('title not unicode', status_code=400)
    if 'description' in request.json and type(request.json['description']) != unicode:
        raise InvalidUsage('description not unicode', status_code=400)
    if 'done' in request.json and type(request.json['done']) is not bool:
        raise InvalidUsage('done not boolean', status_code=400)
    task[0]['title'] = request.json.get('title', task[0]['title'])
    task[0]['description'] = request.json.get('description', task[0]['description'])
    task[0]['done'] = request.json.get('done', task[0]['done'])
    return jsonify({'task': task[0]})

#delete task
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/<int:task_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_task(task_id):
    task = [task for task in tasks if task['id'] == task_id]
    if len(task) == 0:
        raise InvalidUsage('No task to delete', status_code=400)
    tasks.remove(task[0])
    return jsonify({'result': True})


@app.errorhandler(InvalidUsage)
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

EDIT:

Turns out I wasn't setting the request type in POSTMAN correctly. I've updated it to 'application/json' in the header. Now I'm receiving a different error.

> Bad Request Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1
>   column 1 (char 0)

I've tried all the previous steps as before but I continue to get this error.

[image: Badrequest]

EDIT 2:

Per a response below, I tried putting the values into the body of the POST. But I still get back a 400 response.

[image: body]

Comment: Your JSON is a two level structure, while you are reading all data from the top level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image [second postman screenshot] it looks like you pass data in **query string** but `create_task()` expects them in **request body**.

Either replace all occurrences of `request.json` with `request.args` in `create_task()` (to make it work with query params) or leave it as it is and send data in request body.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"title":"Learn more flask","description":"its supper fun"}'
```

Also, take a look at [Get the data received in a Flask request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434599/get-the-data-received-in-a-flask-request).

**EDITED**

Update your `add_todo` to something like

```
@classmethod
def add_todo(cls, task):
    new_todo = cls(title=task["title"], description=task["description"], completed=0)
    db.session.add(new_todo)
    db.session.commit()
```

Related: [generalised insert into sqlalchemy using dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750441/generalised-insert-into-sqlalchemy-using-dictionary).

Comment: I realized I wasn't formatting the raw request properly per your link. I updated it. Now I get the following error. TypeError: add_todo() missing 1 required positional argument: '_description'

Comment: That's a different question. It's because the definition is `add_todo(_title, _description):` but you call it with `Todo.add_todo(task)`.

Comment: Right but there's a description within the task object. It's created on line 80.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I'm not quite sure what's going on with the cls stuff though.

Comment: `cls` is the class on which the method is called, your `Todo` model, in this case. Take a look at https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/ for more details.